# FirebaseError:Firebase Storage: Object 'mark' does not exist

Tags: firebase

this is my regi page

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DXEs.png)
Proceed to membership registration.
but i get an error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrEOg.png)

but it comes into the firestore database just fine.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoD8N.png)

also, when i go to the chat room, there is no value in Object
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKqVu.png)

what should i do???

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW2kH.png)

no object here so
I want the object to receive a value

Comment: Instead of an image of your code, please add the code directly to your question.